# Код отправки письма с вложением, отправляется но ничего не приходит

Tags: email, php, javascript

Может кто то поправит...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /*Fields required to fill*/

      $(".contact_form input[type='text']").focus(function() {
        $(this).css({"border":"1px solid #DEDEDE","background-color":"#FFF"});
        if($(this).val() == "Введите ФИО" || $(this).val() == "Введите E-mail" || $(this).val() == 'Введите корректный E-mail') {
            $(this).val('');
        }

    })

     $(".contact_form textarea").focus(function() {
        $(this).css({"border":"1px solid #DEDEDE","background-color":"#FFF"});
        if($(this).val() == "Введите сообщение") {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    })

    /*/END/Fields required to fill*/

    /*Fields variables*/

    /*FILE UPLOAD*/

        $('#file').change(function() { 
                //$("#preview").html(''); // чистим preview
                $("#preview").html('<img src="/assets/templates/img/load.gif" alt="" />'); //показываем картинку загрузки
                $(".contact_form").ajaxForm({

                    target: '#preview'
                })
            });

    $(".contact_form input[type='submit']").click(function() {
        var formBarName = $(".contact_form input[name='contact_name']").val(),
             formBarEmail = $(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").val(),
             formBarPhone = $(".contact_form input[name='contact_phone_NA_format']").val(),
             formBarBirtdate = $(".contact_form input[name='birth_date']").val(),
             formBarChapter = $(".contact_form input[name='chapter']").val(),
             formBarMess = $(".contact_form textarea").val(),
             formBarHeight = $(".contact_form input[name='height_data']").val(),
             formBarBoobs = $(".contact_form input[name='boobs_size']").val(),
             formBarThaw = $(".contact_form input[name='thawed_size']").val(),
             formBarLoins = $(".contact_form input[name='loins_size']").val(),
             formBarEyes = $(".contact_form input[name='eye_color']").val(),
             formBarHair = $(".contact_form input[name='hair_color']").val(),
             formBarFoot = $(".contact_form input[name='foot_size']").val(),
             formBarFile = $(".contact_form input[name='file']").val();

       /*/END/Fields variables*/

       /*Control set & params setting IF.*/

        if (($(".contact_form input[name='contact_name']").val() == '' || $(".contact_form input[name='contact_name']").val() == 'Введите ФИО') ||
               ($(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").val() == '' || $(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").val() == 'Введите E-mail') || 
                    ($(".contact_form textarea").val() == '' || $(".contact_form textarea").val() == 'Введите сообщение')) {

            $(".contact_form input[name='contact_name']").css({"border":"1px solid red","background-color":"#FFE6DE"});                                                      
            $(".contact_form input[name='contact_name']").val('Введите ФИО');
            $(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").css({"border":"1px solid red","background-color":"#FFE6DE"});
            $(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").val('Введите E-mail');
            $(".contact_form textarea").css({"border":"1px solid red","background-color":"#FFE6DE"});
            $(".contact_form textarea").val('Введите сообщение');

            return false;
        }

        var regEmail = /^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$/;

        if (formBarEmail.search(regEmail) == -1 && $(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").val() != "Введите E-mail") {
            $(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").css({"border":"1px solid red","background-color":"#FFE6DE"});
            $(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").val('Введите корректный E-mail');
            return false;
        }

        /* /END/Control set & params setting IF.*/

        /*AJAX*/

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/assets/templates/mail/questionnaire.php',
            data: 'contact_name=' + formBarName +
                  '&contact_email=' + formBarEmail + 
                  '&contact_phone_NA_format=' + formBarPhone + 
                  '&birth_date=' + formBarBirthdate + 
                  '&chapter=' + formBarChapter + 
                  '&contact_message=' + formBarMess + 
                  '&height_data=' + formBarHeight +
                  '&boobs_size=' + formBarBoobs + 
                  '&thawed_size=' + formBarThaw + 
                  '&loins_size=' + formBarLoins + 
                  '&eye_color=' + formBarEyes +
                  '&hair_color=' + formBarHair + 
                  '&foot_size=' + formBarFoot +
                  '&file=' + formBarFile,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#preview").html('<img src="assets/templates/img/load.gif" alt="JavaScript: Загрузка картинок с помощью jQuery и PHP" />');
            },

            success: function(response) {   
               $("#preview").html();
               $(".place_message").html(response).fadeIn().delay(7000).fadeOut();
               $(".contact_form input[name='contact_name']").val(''); /*Clean fields*/       
               $(".contact_form input[name='contact_email']").val(''); /*Clean fields*/
               $(".contact_form textarea").val(''); /*Clean fields*/
            }
        });
        return false;
    });                    
</script>
```

**Ну вот и собственно код PHP обработчика:**

```
<?php
    function mail_attachment($filename, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) 
    {
        $file = $filename;
        $file_size = filesize($file);
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $name = basename($file);
        $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; 
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."--";
        return mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);     
    }

 $flag = false;

    if (isset($_POST['contact_name'])
         && isset($_POST['contact_email'])
         && isset($_POST['contact_message'])
         && isset($_POST['contact_phone_NA_format'])
         && isset($_POST['birthdate'])
         && isset($_POST['chapter'])
         && isset($_POST['height_data'])
         && isset($_POST['boobs_size'])
         && isset($_POST['thawed_size'])
         && isset($_POST['loins_size'])
         && isset($_POST['eye_color'])
         && isset($_POST['hair_color'])
         && isset($_POST['foot_size'])) 
     {

    $name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $email = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];
    $contact_phone = $_POST['contact_phone_NA_format'];
    $birth = $_POST['birthdate'];
    $chapt = $_POST['chapter'];
    $height = $_POST['height_data'];
    $boobs = $_POST['boobs_size'];
    $thawed = $_POST['thawed_size'];
    $loins = $_POST['loins_size'];
    $eye = $_POST['eye_color'];
    $hair = $_POST['hair_color'];
    $foot = $_POST['foot_size'];

    //Если все правильно выставляем флаг в истину
   $flag = true; 
}

    $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($name)));
    $email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($email)));
    $contact_message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($contact_message)); 
    $contact_phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($contact_phone));
    $birth = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($birth));
    $chapt = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($chapt));
    $height = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($height));
    $boobs = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($boobs));
    $thawed = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($thawed));
    $loins = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($loins));
    $eye = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($eye));
    $hair = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($hair));
    $foot = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($foot));

    $sendto   = "dev_test@bk.ru";       
    $subjectuser  = "Сообщение";
    $headersuser  = "From: Сообщение\r\n";
    $headersuser .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($name) . "\r\n";
    $headersuser .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headersuser .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $my_file = "";
    if (!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) 
     {
    $path = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    if (copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) $my_file = $path; 
     }          
    $my_name = "Письмо с блога";                    
    $my_mail = "my@mail.ru";                        
    $my_replyto = "my@mail.ru";
    $my_message = "<b>Имя:</b> ".$name.
                  "\n<b>Электронный адресс:</b> ".$email.
                  "\n<b>Год рождения:</b>".$birth.
                  "\n<b>Раздел:</b>".$chapt.
                  "\n<b>Рост:</b>".$height.
                  "\n<b>Грудь:</b>".$boobs.
                  "\n<b>Талия:</b>".$thawed.
                  "\n<b>Бедра:</b>".$loins.
                  "\n<b>Цвет глаз:</b>".$eye.
                  "\n<b>Цвет волос:</b>".$hair.
                  "\n<b>Размер обуви:</b>".$foot.
                  "\n<b>Сообщение:</b> ".$contact_message;
    $my_message = nl2br($my_message);

    if(@mail_attachment($my_file, $sendto, $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $subjectuser, $my_message)){
            echo "<div class='message_ok'>Сообщение отправлено</div>";
    } else {
           echo "false";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

вы немного перестарались. Вот это:

```
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    return mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
```

Нужно заменить на это:

```
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

    $body = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $body .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; 
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= "--".$uid."--";
    return mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $header);
```

поидее должно заработать.